# @OneToMany not creating a column in table

Tags: java, spring, jpa, relationship

I've really been trying to solve this but whatever I try it is not working. Throughout other tables it has always worked but with the table I am currently making whatever I do a column that I want creating is never being created. I want a seasons_team table with a list of teams but after finishing the relationship in JPA the column never appears. Is there something wrong I'm doing?
Here is how I am creating the table

```
@Entity
public class SeasonFixtures {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int SeasonFixtureID;
@OneToOne
private Season seasonId;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="season")
private List<Team> teams;

public int getSeasonid() {
return seasonid;
}
public void setSeasonid(int seasonid) {
this.seasonid = seasonid;
 }
 public String getSeasonName() {
return seasonName;
 }
 public void setSeasonName(String seasonName) {
this.seasonName = seasonName;
 }
 public SeasonTeams getSfid() {
return sfid;
 }
 public void setSfid(SeasonTeams sfid) {
this.sfid = sfid;
}
```

And here is the other end of the relationship

```
@Entity
public class Team {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int Team_Id;
private String teamName;
private Blob Logo;
private String stadium;
@OneToOne
private TotalTeamStats tts;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SEASON_ID", referencedColumnName = "seasonid", unique=false)
private Season season;
public String getStadium() {
    return stadium;
}
public void setStadium(String stadium) {
    this.stadium = stadium;
}
public TotalTeamStats getTts() {
    return tts;
}
public void setTts(TotalTeamStats tts) {
    this.tts = tts;
}
public int getTeam_Id() {
    return Team_Id;
}
public void setTeam_Id(int team_Id) {
    Team_Id = team_Id;
}
public String getTeamName() {
    return teamName;
}
public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
}
public Blob getLogo() {
    return Logo;
}
public void setLogo(Blob blobs) {
    Logo = blobs;
}
```

But this is a screenshot of my table in MYSQL

[image of MYSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChlZx.png)

If anyone could help I would be greatly appreciative. I've been trying to fix this for ages. But I don't know where else to turn.

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with your Annotations or your definition of the one to many relation. I could not extract how your one to many relation is defined, but i think its should look like that:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="season")
private Season season;
```

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)


private List<Team> teams;
```

I'm not 100% sure but i think in a one to many relation the @JoinColumn have to be at @ManytoOne site.

**UPDATE**

Maybe because you are using seasonId as Reference. Either Map the relation with the Season Entity or you maybe need to add the Column:

```
@OneToOne
private Season seasonId;
```

to your Table with:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "seasonId")
private Season season;
```

Again just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this creates a third table, any idea how I can make this 3rd table be within the season_fixtures table

Comment: I have no idea how this can happen. Maybe you need to add mapped_by in your OneToMany Annotation: `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "season",  fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`.

Comment: That still doesn't work, I literally don't get it. I've never had any problems with any other of the tables

Comment: Can you maybe add the full class of the other Entitty in your Question?

Comment: Yeah its added now

Comment: Added an update. Really no idea if its the reason but maybe worth a try. And as I mention you have the Relation between seasonId and Team. So maybe you can build the Realation between them?